# Why can we replace $|f|$ with $r+s$ subject to $f = r-s$ and $r,s \geq 0$ in Linear Programming/Optimization?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, absolute-value, linearization

Why can we replace $|f(x_1, \cdots, x_{j\geq 1})|$ with $r+s$ subject to the constraints $f(x_1, \cdots, x_{j \geq 1}) = r-s$ and $r,s \geq 0$ in LP? $f(x_1, \cdots, x_j)$ is either present in the objective function or in the constraints or both.

I have seen ample number of problems where this technique is being followed and I have not come across a proof in support of this. How do I prove that this this works in general (for both maximization and minimization problems)?

Comment: I think the key observation is that if $f = r - s$ and $r, s \geq 0$ then $| f | \leq r + s$. You can see that by trying some examples. For example take $f = 5$ and $r = 5$ and $s = 0$. Or take $f = 5$ and $r = 7$ and $s = 2$. Using this observation, I think you can convince yourself that the optimal value of the reformulated problem is equal to the optimal value of the original problem (and, if $x$ is optimal for the reformulated problem, then $x$ is also optimal for the original problem, and vice versa).

Comment: @littleO If $f = r-s$ then $-r-s \leq r-s \leq r+s$ since both $r,s$ are non-negative. But how do we know that the optimal solution will necessarily have $\min(r,s) = 0$? When this a part of the objective function and it's a minimization problem, I get that the positivity of $|f|$ gives us the result. What if it's a maximization problem? Also, how does this substitution work for constraints?

Comment: The idea is that: when considering candidate solutions for the reformulated problem, if $\min(r,s) \neq 0$ then $r + s$ is larger than necessary and so we have not found the optimal values of $r$ and $s$. If $r$ and $s$ are chosen optimally, then $r + s$ will be as small as possible, which means that $r + s$ will be equal to $|f|$.

Comment: @littleO I don't understand exactly why $r+s$ has to be the smallest when it is a constraint (say $\displaystyle\sum_{i >j}^{n} c_{ri} x_i + \left| f(x_1, \cdots, x_j) \right| \leq b_r$ being replaced with $\displaystyle\sum_{i >j}^{n} c_{ri} x_i + (r+s) \leq b_r$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crucially it only works for convex use of the operator, e.g., minimization with it entering with  positive constant, or in a constraint entering with a positive constant (to the left of $\leq$). The general case is nonconvex and is not LP-representable (although MIlP-representable).

Let $x = a - b$ and replace $|x| = a-b$ where the intention is that optimality implies $a = \max(x,0)$ and $b = \max(-x,0)$.

Now assume you instead obtain a solution with $a = \max(x,0) + \epsilon $ and $b = \max(-x,0) + \epsilon $ and study what happens if you assume this is an optimal solution (hint: if $|x|$ enters the minimization with a positive sign, how does $\epsilon$ enter the objective, and what does a non-zero $\epsilon$ tell you about optimality...)

If the term only is used in the constraints, and the constraint is inactive at optimality, correctness is not important. If the constraint is tight at optimality, using the same principle as for the objective, $\epsilon$ will be driven to 0.

Comment: I understand the case for minimization and when $\text{Cost }= g + |f|$.

Comment: What I don't understand is the case when $|f|$ is a part of (one or more) constraints. Say the constraint $\displaystyle\sum_{i >j}^{n} c_{ri} x_i + \left| f(x_1, \cdots, x_j) \right| \leq b_r$ is being replaced with $\displaystyle\sum_{i >j}^{n} c_{ri} x_i + (r+s) \leq b_r$. Why exactly will the optima have $\min(r,s) = 0$?

Comment: If you have $g + |x|  \leq 1$ and you have replaced with $g + (a + b) \leq 1$. If both $a$ and $b$ are non-zero, you can write them as $a = \tilde{a} + \epsilon $ and $b = \tilde{b} +\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is positive and $\tilde{a}$ and $\tilde{b}$ are non-negative.  Hence you have  $g + (\tilde a + \tilde b)  + 2\epsilon \leq 1$. If this binding, the optimizer would gain from decreasing $\epsilon$ to 0.

Comment: Why does $\epsilon \to 0$? This is a constraint and **not** the cost. I am sorry I don't understand this.

Comment: It only does if the constraint is binding, i.e. hindering the optimal solution from decreasing. If the optimal solution can be improved by decreasing $\epsilon$ it will do that, otherwise it is leaving performance on the table. If the original constraint is not binding, nothing says $\epsilon$ will go to zero. The value of absolute value model is only valid if some constraint and objective term involving it has made the solver reduce $\epsilon$ to improve optimality.

Comment: That means we **may** have solutions to $r,s$ such that $\min(r,s) \neq 0$. However, every time we have a solution $(r,s)$ with $r,s > 0$, we will always have another solution that satisfies $\min(r,s) = 0$ and the optimum cost does not reduce. This is because the constraints, cost or both will always have $k\epsilon$  strictly greater than $0$. I understand this completely now, thank you very much!